# Having issues extracting from json

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, here-api

i've been through a lot of the threads here and tried different options but i seem to continually do something wrong..
I manage to get the JSON correctly but i cant seem to parse the parts i want. I'm using the reverse geocode request on developer.here.com

i've tried creating different structs and substructs but nothing seemed to work. I'd appreciate any help as i've gone hours trying to fix this...

(p.s im new to JSON)
heres the dict, i've been trying to extract the label thats under address , also heres a link since i couldnt make it look nice https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode :

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2019-04-04T17:45:06.052+0000",
      "NextPageInformation": "2"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "Distance": 13.6,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "State": 1,
              "County": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "District": 1,
              "Street": [
                1
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1,
              "PostalCode": 1
            },
            "MatchType": "pointAddress",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_Opil2LPZVRLZjlWNLJQuWB_0ITN",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 41.88432,
                "Longitude": -87.63877
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 41.88449,
                  "Longitude": -87.63877
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 41.8854442,
                  "Longitude": -87.64028
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 41.8831958,
                  "Longitude": -87.63726
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "425 W Randolph St, Chicago, IL 60606, United States",
                "Country": "USA",
                "State": "IL",
                "County": "Cook",
                "City": "Chicago",
                "District": "West Loop",
                "Street": "W Randolph St",
                "HouseNumber": "425",
                "PostalCode": "60606",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "United States",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Illinois",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Cook",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "N",
                    "key": "PostalCodeType"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "MapReference": {
                "ReferenceId": "776372180",
                "MapId": "NAAM191N0",
                "MapVersion": "Q1/2019",
                "MapReleaseDate": "2019-01-28",
                "Spot": 0.52,
                "SideOfStreet": "right",
                "CountryId": "21000001",
                "StateId": "21002247",
                "CountyId": "21002623",
                "CityId": "21002647",
                "BuildingId": "9000000000002726912",
                "AddressId": "79186508",
                "RoadLinkId": "170008450"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

```
  struct Welcome: Codable {
    let response: Response

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let metaInfo: MetaInfo
    let view: [View]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaInfo = "MetaInfo"
        case view = "View"
    }
}

struct MetaInfo: Codable {
    let timestamp, nextPageInformation: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timestamp = "Timestamp"
        case nextPageInformation = "NextPageInformation"
    }
}

struct View: Codable {
    let type: String
    let viewID: Int
    let result: [Result]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "_type"
        case viewID = "ViewId"
        case result = "Result"
    }
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let relevance: Int
    let distance: Double
    let matchLevel: String
    let matchQuality: MatchQuality
    let matchType: String
    let location: Location

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case relevance = "Relevance"
        case distance = "Distance"
        case matchLevel = "MatchLevel"
        case matchQuality = "MatchQuality"
        case matchType = "MatchType"
        case location = "Location"
    }
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let locationID, locationType: String
    let displayPosition: DisplayPosition
    let navigationPosition: [DisplayPosition]
    let mapView: MapView
    let address: Address
    let mapReference: MapReference

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case locationID = "LocationId"
        case locationType = "LocationType"
        case displayPosition = "DisplayPosition"
        case navigationPosition = "NavigationPosition"
        case mapView = "MapView"
        case address = "Address"
        case mapReference = "MapReference"
    }
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let label, country, state, county: String
    let city, district, street, houseNumber: String
    let postalCode: String
    let additionalData: [AdditionalDatum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case label = "Label"
        case country = "Country"
        case state = "State"
        case county = "County"
        case city = "City"
        case district = "District"
        case street = "Street"
        case houseNumber = "HouseNumber"
        case postalCode = "PostalCode"
        case additionalData = "AdditionalData"
    }
}

struct AdditionalDatum: Codable {
    let value, key: String
}

struct DisplayPosition: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "Latitude"
        case longitude = "Longitude"
    }
}

struct MapReference: Codable {
    let referenceID, mapID, mapVersion, mapReleaseDate: String
    let spot: Double
    let sideOfStreet, countryID, stateID, countyID: String
    let cityID, buildingID, addressID, roadLinkID: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case referenceID = "ReferenceId"
        case mapID = "MapId"
        case mapVersion = "MapVersion"
        case mapReleaseDate = "MapReleaseDate"
        case spot = "Spot"
        case sideOfStreet = "SideOfStreet"
        case countryID = "CountryId"
        case stateID = "StateId"
        case countyID = "CountyId"
        case cityID = "CityId"
        case buildingID = "BuildingId"
        case addressID = "AddressId"
        case roadLinkID = "RoadLinkId"
    }
}

struct MapView: Codable {
    let topLeft, bottomRight: DisplayPosition

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case topLeft = "TopLeft"
        case bottomRight = "BottomRight"
    }
}

struct MatchQuality: Codable {
    let country, state, county, city: Int
    let district: Int
    let street: [Int]
    let houseNumber, postalCode: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case country = "Country"
        case state = "State"
        case county = "County"
        case city = "City"
        case district = "District"
        case street = "Street"
        case houseNumber = "HouseNumber"
        case postalCode = "PostalCode"
    }
}


guard let jsonString = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else {return}
            print (jsonString)//it prints the json correctly
            let address_label = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Address.self, from: data)
            print(address_label) //prints out nil
            // some more code here that catches errors
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking but I recommend using `Codable` and to get  the structs needed to decode your json you can use https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: im asking how i can extract the field that i need from this json, oh um so after .i get all the structs how can i assign a certain variable to be equal to them?

Comment: right now im getting nil, i tried the site that @JoakimDanielson suggested and copy pasted the structs but when i try to do the print of Address.self, i get nil.. not even the entire array :\

Comment: `catch` errors. Decodable errors are extremely descriptive. And (learn to) **read** the JSON. The structure is very clear and there are only two different collection types.

Comment: IN your example Response contains View, and View contains Result, and Result contains Location. Your structs are not following this structure.

Comment: please note my previous comment where i used the app.quicktype.io to get my new structs but then when printing i still get nil

Comment: Once again **Catch** the error!. It tells you immediately what's wrong and where. **Never ever** `try?` while decoding JSON  with `Decodable`.

Comment: @vadian i do catch the error.. its just not shown but it doesnt throw the error of that catch so its not that

Comment: No, I'm sorry, do you do not catch **the** error. You are catching the – in this case – completely meaningless `JSONSerialization` error.

Comment: what do you mean ? @vadian i have  }
            catch let jsonError {
                print("Error doing a JSONSerilization", jsonError)
                
            }

Comment: Remove the question mark after `try`. `try?` ignores the error. The `Decoding` error is crucial, not the `JSONSerialization` error.

Comment: so i get now "Error doing a JSONSerilization keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Label", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Label\", intValue: nil) (\"Label\").", underlyingError: nil))" @vadian

Comment: You have to decode the **root** object, not something on a deeper level.

Comment: @vadian okay so following what Joakim said, im not sure what im supposed to do after i decode welcome.self, beause when i try to print out his code i get more decoding errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Label", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Label\", intValue: nil) (\"Label\").", underlyingError: nil))"

is pretty clear. It can mean

1. The mentioned key does not exist in the JSON. This is not the case as the key `Label` does exist.
2. You are decoding the wrong struct. **This is the case** as the root object is `Welcome`.

You have to decode always the root object of the JSON and get deeper levels by accessing the properties. Use Code Completion, it'll help you.

Comment: how can i get to deeper levels ?

Comment: Please read my answer. Type `let address = address_label.` and see what Code Completion suggests. You get the `Address` level with `.response.view[0].result[0].location.address`

Comment: yes so i did :
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
                let addrs = result.response.view[0].result[0].location.address.label
                print(addrs)

but then i get . Error doing a JSONSerilization keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "CountryId", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Response", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "View", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "Result", intValue: nil), .....  @vadian

Comment: * Sigh *.  The structs in the question do match the given JSON without errors. The **real** JSON seems to be larger. The error says that in one of the records the key `CountryId` does not exist. You have to declare those properties as optional (`String?`). And the error message is incomplete by the way.

Comment: i'm sorry ): i know its like talking to a kid that doesnt understand but im new to this and youve been very helpful. let me try what you said

Comment: Thank you kindly. I got it (: